# Summing or even performing more complex mathematical operations (multiply, add a constant, ...) two GDAL grids

Tags: raster, gdal, mathematics

I have two grids with same cell size, same starting position (top left) and same grid size. I want to sum the grids and create a sum grid as an result:

e.g. grid A + grid B = grid C

How can I achieve that with GDAL if my grids are not identical (1) in grid size (2) in starting position and (3) in cell size?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gdal_calc.py Python library to achieve this.

http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py

Here all the files have to be the same dimension. I still do not know how to accomplish this if grid's are not in the same size.